# has BREW MP JVM?

Tags: brew-framework, brewmp

If BREW MP has JVM ( java - car ) , If it supports all Java ( J2ME Applications),
There is no need to develop applications through BREW , TBT etc....is it true?

Answer (score 1):

In slide 10 of [this "BrewMP Overview" Uplinq 2010 presentation](http://www.uplinq.com/pdf/SS_BrewMP_Overview_The_OS_for_Mass-Market_Smartphones_77.pdf), you can see that there are several frameworks available with BrewMP, including Java.

The biggest benefit of Java is its wide-ranging compatibility, but to actually achieve this compatibility also restricts you to the most common denominator of features across the platforms, as well as the "Java sandbox" that gives you very limited access to the phone. For many applications this is a good tradeoff to make and that's why Java apps are widely found.

BrewMP apps, with correct permissions, can interact with most components of the phone - connectivity, hardware sensors, contact / messaging databases, etc. which allows you to have very deep integration with the device. When a developer wants the experience to be seamless, it usually means choosing a particular platform that is used on the device, and working with it.

Answer (score 1):

HTC Smart and HTC Freestyle are already equipped with Java VM (J2ME) while shipping.

HTC Freestyle:
http://www.mobileheart.com/cell-phone-reviews/htc-25/htc-Freestyle-2578.aspx